# What is the difference in meaning between "be going to" and "will" with an "if-clause" in the context of showing someone around?

Tags: difference, future-tense

What is the difference in meaning between *be going to* and *will* with an *if-clause* in the context of showing someone around? For example:

> If you look to the right, you **will** see an old castle.
>
> If you look to the right, you **are going to** see an old castle.

Answer (score 1):

There is no significant difference in meaning.

The *going to* version could be considered slightly less formal.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation. "You are going to see" suggests that something is not visible yet (i.e. 'you will soon be able to see'). It would be valid on a bus tour if the castle is not yet visible from the bus, but will be in a moment.

If the castle is visible at the current moment, another option is:

- If you look to the right, you **can** see an old castle.

The one with "you will" (or informally, "you'll") is perfectly idiomatic to say in either situation.